# Angular infinite HTTP polling loop without Rx.interval

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm working with an API that implements a long polling loop, as in the server keeps connections open for an arbitrary amount of time (say between 0 and 5s) then returns a response as soon as it has a new message to transmit.

Currently my code sends a request every 5s, regardless of when the server responds.
If there's 3 requests in a row, and the server responds in [1s, 2s, 3s], then currently I will be sending 3 requests [5s, 5s, 5s] for a total of ~15s when ideally I would want it to all happen in 6s (1 + 2 + 3).

```js
Rx.interval(5000)
  .pipe(
    Rx.concatMap(() => httpClient.get('/api/messages')),
    retry(8000)
   )
  .subscribe((data) => handleResponse(data));
```

If it was a promise I would write something such as

```js
const fetchRequest = httpClient.get('/api/messages').toPromise()
  .then(data => {handleResponse(data); fetchRequest()});
```

but in my case I need to end up returning an Obvservable.

From reading the RxJS docs, what seems to be the closest to what I want would be `retryWhen`, which would work but seems semantically wrong to me, as it would force me to raise an `Error` to keep the loop going.

```js
httpClient.get('/api/messages')),
  .subscribe((data) => {
    handleResponse(data);
    throw 'keep going';
  })
  .retryWhen(val => val === 'keep going')
```

Is there a more elegant way than using `retryWhen` to handle this case?

Comment: You should take a look at the `expand` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to send request to the server and after while when you get response, again you want to send new request.

[StackBlitz live demo for this code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-infinite-http-polling-loop-without-rxinterval?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**This is example exactly for that behavior.**

```
import { Observable, Subject, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, delay, startWith, tap, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  subject = new Subject();

  constructor() {

    this.subject.pipe(
      startWith({}),
      concatMap(() => this.testGet()),
      tap(() => this.subject.next()),
    ).subscribe(x => {
      console.log('inside subscribe', x);
    })

  }

  async testGet() {
    console.log('start get');
    await of({}).pipe(delay(2000)).toPromise();
    console.log('finish get');
    return null;
  }
}
```